# Calling file from remote directory using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a basic powershell script that runs great in its local directories.  I am very new to powershell so this may be a basic question.  The csv file really will sit in the following directory \ADdata.acdsd.internal\F\Exports\Google\Student Accounts.  How do I reference this directory in my code below. Do I need to replace the $list command with some other command.

```
     $list = Import-Csv studentaccounts.csv
     foreach ($entry in $list)
     {
     C:\gam-rcsdkids\gam.exe create user $($entry.newuser) firstname $($entry.firstname) lastname                              $($entry.lastname) password $($entry.password)
      }
```

Comment: PowerShell supports UNC paths so if its just the CSV then this should work: `$list = Import-Csv "\\ADdata.acdsd.internal\F\Exports\Google\Student Accounts\studentaccounts.csv"` assuming people have the proper permissions to this share / directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell supports UNC paths without problems, so first of all try to invoke:

```
cd \\ADdata.acdsd.internal\F\Exports\Google\Student Accounts\
```

If above command works you should call below line to import CSV:

```
$list = Import-Csv \ADdata.acdsd.internal\F\Exports\Google\Student Accounts\
```

Now why I started with `cd`: because if there is a problem with accessing share you will see better in `cd` command (there won't be errors about csv file)

Comment: I have tested this myself and it works perfectly as long as you have read access.